# Does the distance between points determine the shape?

Tags: matrices, geometry

Given three pairwise distances between three unknown points in a plane, the positions of the triangle vertices are uniquely determined up to a rotation and translation.

Is this true for an arbitrary amount of points in $n$ dimensions? that is:

> Given $(m-1)m/2$ distances between $m$ unknown points in $\mathbb{R}^n$, are the positions of the points ${\bf p}_i$ determined up to an orthogonal matrix and a translation? i.e, can we determine ${\bf q}_i$ such that:
>   $${\bf p}_i = {\bf{ R}} \cdot {\bf q}_i + {\bf{ t}}$$
>   For some vector $\bf{t}$ and orthogonal ${\bf R}$?

Intuitively, this result seems true, but it would be nice to see how one could go about proving this.

Comment: I think giving a construction should suffice, assuming it is possible. You will need at most $n$ distances per point though.

Comment: The object you describe is in fact called a $\textit{simplex}$ in simplicial homology if $m=n$, and it is indeed "rigid" since it has a fixed volume: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex#Volume . If you want more points glue together some simplices.

Comment: @Nimda - not quite, since $m+1\neq n$, but simplex volume is a good start.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned $m=n+1$ instead of $m=n$.